# Can't deduce template parameter

Tags: c++, templates, c++11

I have the following class structure, which tries to generate a compile time generated tree hierarchy

```
struct NodeBase{
   virtual constexpr uint32_t size() const = 0;
   virtual constexpr bool empty() const = 0;
   constexpr NodeBase(){};
};

template <size_t L>
class Node : NodeBase{
private: 
   const uint32_t * const ptr;
   const std::array<const NodeBase &, L> nodes;

 public: 
   constexp Node(std::initializer_list<NodeBase> const ts, uint32_t const * const ptr) :
      NodeBase(),
      ptr(ptr),
         nodes{ts}
      {
      };
   constexpr uint32_t size() const {
       return nodes.size();
   }
   constexpr bool empty() const {
       return (ptr==nullptr) ? true : false;
   }
}

// helper function should allow for template deduction
template<size_t T>
constexpr Node<T> makeNode(std::initializer_list<NodeBase> const ts, uint32_t const * const ptr){
   return Node<T>(ts, ptr);
};

template <size_t L>
class Item : Node{
public: 
   constexpr Item() :
       Node<L>({member}, nullptr)
   {
   };
private : 
   // here lies the problem
   template <size_t M>
   static constexpr Node<M> member = makeNode({},nullptr);
}
```

However, this gives the compiler (gcc 4.9.1) error:
no matching function call to makeNode(, null_ptr_t), and a note to say it couldn't deduce template type.

I can fix the error by moving parameter M into the class level template, but this has some fairly horrible consequences, in that the parameter list will grow at every level of the tree hierarchy. I'm sure the compiler should be able to deduce the type, which is conditional on the length of the initialiser list provided to the constructor. Any thoughts?

Comment: Is that a variable template? If so, shouldn't this question be tagged c++14 rather than c++11? Also, the Node constructor is declared constexpr, but the `makeNode` function is not, so I don't think the member can be constructed at compile-time the way it is right now.

Comment: I've tried it with contexpr on makeNode, no changes

Comment: JorenHeit: C++ is C++14. no need to tag it 14 or 11.

Comment: @JohanLundberg I disagree, many projects don't use C++14 (or 11 for that matter), so tagging as the correct version gives more information for answerers (although I personally assume C++11 at this point).

Comment: @OllieB I didn't mean to say that that would solve the issue. I'm just confused on what you are trying to do. Is your intention to have a variable template? How/where is the type `M` decided? Is it dependent on `L` in some way?

Comment: M is independent of L. It is dependant entirely on the number of elements inside the initialiser list passed to makeNode, and it can be set manually based on this ( my current workaround). I was just hopeing to reduce typing by making it infer the correct number for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your comment, I think this is what you might want. I abandoned the use of `std::initializer_list`. In C++14 it should have a `constexpr` member to return the number of elements, but I couldn't get this to work and you tagged your question C++11 anyway. Instead, I'm using a plain old C array, of which the size can be deduced by the template mechanism.

```
template <size_t M>
struct Node {};

template <size_t M>
constexpr Node<M> makeNode(int const (&list)[M])
{
    return Node<M>();
}

class Item
{
    static constexpr auto member = makeNode({1, 2, 3});
};
```

Note that the use of `auto` at class scope only works for static members, but you seem to meet this requirement.

Answer (score 3):

How compiler should deduce template type, if there is no usage of template type in function parameters?
May be you want

```
static constexpr Node<M> member = makeNode<M>({},nullptr);
```

Comment: The problem with using L is that the array of child codes at each level of the heirarchy then have to be the same length, which isn't desired.

Comment: I could manually define the length (0,1,2 etc), but I was hoping for something more generic

Comment: You could use `std::array<NodeBase,T>` instead, which should do the deduction (untested).

Comment: @TartanLlama where should I put that, and if you mean in Node, that creates a copy of the entire tree.